# How to detect Android audiostream underflow/overflow?

Tags: android

I'm currently using the AudioRecord java object to receive audio from the microphone. Sometimes I don't pull data sufficiently fast (E.g, when an application switch occurs). Is there any method for me to know that the audiostream was interrupted with an audiobuffer underflow ?

Answer (score 6):

You might try using the [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) class instead of AudioRecord, which offers a few extra methods, including the ability to register an error callback method. I'm not sure if all versions of Android will call that in case of an underrun, though. If you get callbacks here, that would probably be the "cleaner" solution.

The other solution is that you can measure the time taken when polling for audio and determine if an underrun has occurred. Basically, you'd store the time in a local variable before calling `read()` and then again afterwards:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
int bytesRead = read(...);
long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

You'll probably want to use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`, even though the time in nanoseconds is not very accurate it will be more accurate than the system's millisecond precision. Then, using the sample rate and the buffer size, you can calculate the expected number of milliseconds this call should take with:

```
long maxMilliseconds = (bufferSize / getSampleRate()) * 1000;
```

If the elapsed time is greater than this value, then an audio dropout has probably occurred and you can trigger your error handler.

Also note that the `AudioRecord.read()` methods return the number of bytes actually read from the device. You should compare this to the number of bytes you expected to read, as that's a very easy way to detect buffer underruns as well.

Comment: I like the first option and will try to see whether it detects underruns. I'm very sceptical of your 'timing' solution. I tried something similar in C++, on Linux with OSS and learned that the scheduling of the operating system often comes into play with this strategy. The third option has no meaning since the number of bytes does not relate to whether an underrun occured or not. It might simply be a internal buffer boundary that provides few bytes than what was requested.

Comment: In my experience writing ALSA drivers (which IIRC is also used in Android), buffer underruns can indeed be detected by looking at the return value of the `read()` call. Also, I see no reason to ignore this value as long as the system provides it for you.

Comment: Well I assume that _when an underflow occurs_ the read will be short. However, when a read is short it does not mean that it was due to an underflow. Nevertheless, once a callback is called that tells me that an underflow occured, one can probably expect that the next read will be short. Well, unless it exactly matches the buffesize. You know this is truly a mess. I'll first see how that callback works. If it does indeed report underflows, then the award is yours. How I deal with the part of the buffer that I still want to see and that what I don't want to see is something else.

Comment: You are correct -- when a short read occurs, that does not necessarily mean an underflow occurred, but again, my experience with ALSA is that any type of weirdness during reading (including the time measurement stuff) is a good indicator of potential underruns. I agree that Android's API for audio is not ideal, and my solution isn't either. :) Anyways, depending on what your app needs, I'd suggest trying one or more of the above and then using it to show a warning rather than a hard error. Also please report back to let me know what worked best for you.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think you mean overflow, rather than underrun.  I have the same question, but for an overflow.  For underruns, the read method simply blocks until enough data is ready.

Comment: The read method might or might not block, it doesn't tell me anything about the continuity of the signal I received.